# using domain name for each user?

Tags: apache, web-applications

I hope I could clearly explained it here,

I have a web apps let's say it is www.mywebapps.com/user_name

now the user want to create a domain name for himself like www.user_name.net and the access will be show what in www.mywebapps.com/user_name

so forexample 
www.mywebapps.com/user_name/show/1
it would be accessible from 
www.user_name.net/show/1 as well

how to accomplish this task ? is it possible ?

Comment: I think this question may be more suited to serverfault http://serverfault.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The user must first register the domain!

Do you really mean a subdomain ?
Like user-name.mywebapps.com (underscores are not legal in domain names)

Either way you want to use mod_rewrite.

Subdomains are much easier than newly registered names because you will need to modify the webserver for each name. for only a few thats easy for may that's hard. For a subdomain its simply a wildcard and a mod_rewrite command in either the virtual hosts config or the .htaccess file if you don't have access to the virtual hosts config

DC

You will need to add the domain to your virtual hosts configuration. the easiest way would be create a new virtualhost for each new users domain name. Then set the documentroot to that users subfolder.

For example if the documentroot for the main site is

```
/home/mywebapps/public_html
```

Then in the users virtual host give it a document root of

```
/home/mywebapps/public_html/username
```

This would be fine for a static or simple site. for a more complex dynamic site you may be better of using mod_rewrite.

DC

Comment: yes the user will register the domain by himself. I just create a web apps for all users with access like www.mywebapps.com/username and then they could register a domain name like www.usernameown.com to go to www.mywebapps.com/username (but not using frame).

Answer (score 0):

You would have to pay to register the domain name every time.  And wait for the name to propagate through the DNS servers, which can take a while.

You might instead look at using subdomains - something like `user_name.mywebapps.com`

Answer (score 0):

Check out Apache support for virtual hosts:

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/vhosts/

But obviously you must register the domain names desired (Apache won't magically do that for you :-)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the **mod_vhost_alias** module. You will handle in one configuration file all the Virtualhosts, with variables for DocumentRoot and ServerName. So with this module you can map the DocumentRoot of each name based virtualhost on each home user directory.